# two rdlc reports in one pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, rdlc

I am using .net 4.0 and RDLC reports to export some reports to pdf. The reports are self standing and are rendered in separate pdfs but in some scenarios I would like to render two or more RDLC reports in one pdf as separate pages.

Is there a way to achieve this? I already tried concatenating the byte arrays returned from

```
Report.Render("PDF")
```

but this doesn't work (headers perhaps).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/).  It has the ability to merge documents on the fly

Comment: Well I had some difficulties with setting it up together with the .NET reports. Is there may be an another alternative

Comment: Sorry I've got no experience with .NET reports.  If you have any normal PDFs however iTextSharp can read them in and combine them.  So you could save your reports to disk - then run an iTextSharp routine

Comment: What sort of troubles?  If RDLC uses iTextSharp under the hood, installing your own version could cause some odd conflicts.  OTOH, it should already be available.